# The server immediately return to the ajax post without executing a code for redirect

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

What i am trying to do here was to pass the form values to a function in controller via jquery ajax post upon submit.

here's the code for the view

```
<form  action="<?php echo site_url('products/paypal')?>" method="post" id="checkoutForm" name="checkoutForm">
   ...
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
   ...
   $.post($('#checkoutForm').attr('action'), $('#checkoutForm').serialize());
   ...
</script>
```

The controller will process the post variables then should execute this line of code `$this->paypal->pay();` that will redirect the user to other url.
Here's the code for a function in the controller (products.php)

```
public function paypal() {
    //... paypal configuration
    $this->paypal->pay(); //Proccess the payment
}
```

Here's the code for a function in the library (Paypal.php)

```
function pay(){

    #Convert the array to url encode variables 
    $vars =  http_build_query($this->config);

    if($this->config['production'] == TRUE){
        header('LOCATION:'.$this->production_url.$vars);
    }else{
        header('LOCATION:'.$this->sandbox_url.$vars);
    }
}
```

The problem is that the user is not being redirected. What could be the problem in this one?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you make an Ajax form submission from the client, you'll never be able to do a browser redirect from the server. That's the difference between a regular request and an Ajax one. Either you'll need to do a regular form submission or you'll need to change the window location on the client side after the Ajax call returns.